# Web Scraping coded price

Tags: python, html, function, web-scraping, price

While web scraping an article the price was in the elements but not in in resources. instead there is the following coded text

```html
<script>
var f3699334f586f4f2bb6edc10899026d63 = function(value) { 
    return base64UTF8Codec.decode(arguments[0])
};

replaceWith(
    document.getElementById('9ad80ca8-79ac-4fd8-8998-cb6662e8cc9a'), 
    f3699334f586f4f2bb6edc10899026d63('CiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8c3BhbiBjbGFzcz0icHVsbC1yaWdodCI+IDIuNTkwLC0gPC9zcGFuPgogICAgICAgICAgICA=')
);
</script>
```

How can I decode the text into price ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please have a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 To answer your question: The page is loaded by filling additional data with javascript.

Comment: having the url is nearly always helpful when public and not behind a login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text is base64 encoded. If you can locate with beautifulsoup the right `<script>` tag, you can extract the right information with `re` module:

```
import re
import base64
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''<script>
var f3699334f586f4f2bb6edc10899026d63 = function(value){return base64UTF8Codec.decode(arguments[0])};
replaceWith(document.getElementById('9ad80ca8-79ac-4fd8-8998-cb6662e8cc9a'), f3699334f586f4f2bb6edc10899026d63('CiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8c3BhbiBjbGFzcz0icHVsbC1yaWdodCI+IDIuNTkwLC0gPC9zcGFuPgogICAgICAgICAgICA='));
</script>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

# 1. locate the right <script> tag
script = soup.script

# 2. get coded text from the script tag
coded_text = re.findall(r".*\('(.*?)'\)\);", script.text)[0]

# 3. decode the text
decoded_text = base64.b64decode(coded_text)  # b'\n                <span class="pull-right"> 2.590,- </span>\n            '

# 4. get the price from the decoded text
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(decoded_text, 'html.parser')

print(soup2.span.get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
2.590,-
```